# How to create object names java

Tags: java

Lets say I need to create lot of class objects for my main class so I was wondering if there was any way to create a loop that creates a new class object many times but each time it changes the name if the class object.

Hey I know you might be thinking why would you want to have multiple class objects that are the same for a program but I want to do something similar but I dont want to release my code for it. I will give a sample of the code if it is needed though

EDIT:I want my class classnamehere to take user input and every time they type something like "open that thing" It would create a new class object

Comment: What is a "class object for my main class"?  Do you mean an instance of your main class, or an actual object that is an instance of class `Class`?

Comment: Looks like you already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218607/java-creating-a-class-from-a-string

Answer (score 1):

use a map .. use the string as the key and an object instance as the value.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is to create set of objects of the same class and identify them uniquely - best thing is to create an array and initialize each via a loop...

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can take a ArrayList like this:

```
List<YourClassType> list=new ArrayList<YourClassType>();
```

the put a for loop for how many objects you wanna create:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
list.add(new YourClassType());
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code will be of great help, but can you not use an array of your class and create objects in a loop?

for example if there is a class named Example.

```
Example[] e = new Example[200];
for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
 e[i]=new Example();
}
```

You can use a List too if you want more objects to be added dynamically.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a factory for object creation; within the factory you can have a naming strategy.